# Эмуляция кликов и запись положения курсора ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

Нужно сделать эмуляцию кликов и запись в переменную текущего положения курсора на экране и использование его (Перемещение на эту точку через определенный промежуток времени). 
Необходимо сделать через ctypes, пример необходимого на pyautogui:

```py
import pyautogui
import time
print("Пять секунд до записи положения экрана")
time.sleep(5)
pos = pyautogui.position()
print("Положение №1 успешно было записано!")
print("Положение №2 будет записано через пять секунд")
time.sleep(5)
postwo = pyautogui.position()
print("Цикл начнется через пять секунд")
z = 0
while z < 4:
   pyautogui.moveTo(pos)
   time.sleep(0.01)
   pyautogui.click()
   time.sleep(0.01)
   pyautogui.moveTo(postwo)
   time.sleep(0.01)
   pyautogui.click()
   time.sleep(0.01)
   z = z + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from ctypes import windll, Structure, c_long, byref
import time


class POINT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', c_long), ('y', c_long)]


def lmb_click():
    windll.user32.mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    windll.user32.mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0, 0)


def set_cursor_position(x, y):
    windll.user32.SetCursorPos(x, y)


def get_cursor_position():
    pt = POINT()
    windll.user32.GetCursorPos(byref(pt))
    return pt.x, pt.y


x, y = get_cursor_position()
time.sleep(5)
set_cursor_position(x, y)
lmb_click()
```

Comment: Я использую python 3, по этому скорее всего половина кода не работает. Так же, у вас обязательно должны быть 'x, y', из-за этого мне это не подходит

Comment: Во-первых, этот код абсолютно одинаково работает и во втором и в третьем Python. Я написал его как раз в Python 3.6.3. Во-вторых, почему не подходит? В чём принципиальное отличие использования кортежа `(x, y)`, возвращаемого из `pyautogui.position()`, от двух переменных `x` и `y`? В-третьих, необязательно, это очень легко исправить.